# Execute mysql_query with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a cart with products in it. I have a delete button for each product. What I want is to execute mysql_query:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM bim_cart WHERE coupon_id = '{$_GET['delete']}' AND session_code = '{$_SESSION['code']}'");
```

Code for button:

```
<div class="remove">
<a href="<?php echo $address . '/index.php?lang=lv&page=cart&delete=' . $item['id'];?>" class="color2">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw color2"></i>
</a>
```

It is possible to do without reloading page, but refresh information?

Comment: yes you can do this with the help of ajax... google it you ll find plenty of solutions

Comment: ...and stop using `mysql_` function in your code. They are deprecated.

Comment: ..and when you do use ajax make sure to properly escape your $_GET variables, and DON'T put $_GET variables straight into SQL queries. They are dangerous.

Comment: *Yes, it is possible.* [**But please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AJAX request you can solve this. Try some thing like this

**IN HTML page**

```
<div class="remove" id="id-<?=$item['id']?>">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="<?=$item['id']?>" class="color2">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw color2"></i>
</a>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.color2').live('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php'
            ,data:{delete: id}
            ,type: 'GET'
            ,success:function(data){
                if(data == 'success')
                {
                    //clear your deleted product div/html element something like below
                    $('#id-' + id).remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Add a PHP file delete.php & perform delete operation**

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $delete_id = $_GET['delete'];
    $deleted = mysql_query("DELETE FROM bim_cart WHERE coupon_id = '$delete_id' AND session_code = '{$_SESSION['code']}'");
    if($deleted){
       echo 'success';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the argument to your function

```
<a onClick="deleteProduct(<?echo $id_to_delete;?>)"...></a>
```

In script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteProduct(id){
    $.post("delete.php", {id: id});
return false;
}
</script>
```

write the query in the delete page

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM bim_cart WHERE coupon_id = '{$_GET['delete']}' AND session_code = '{$_SESSION['code']}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var delete_id= "<?php echo $item['id'] ; ?> "; 
var session_id="<?php echo $_SESSION['code'] ;?>";
$.ajax({
       type:"post",
       datatype:"html",
       url:"cart.php",
       data:"delete_id="+delete_id+"&session_id=session_id,
       success:(data){
          /*put return data here */
      }



    })
```

now make cart.php page

```
     <?php
       $delete_id=$_POST['delete_id'];
       $ses_id=$_POST['session_id'];

       now perform your sql query 
   ?>
```